# What is the decoherence rate and the thermal de Broglie wavelength in quantum Brownian motion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, diffusion, brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

I know that
when the thermal de Broglie wavelength is on the order of the interparticle distance, the gas must be treated as a Fermi gas or a Bose gas, depending on the nature of the gas particles. I would like to know how much change in the decoherence rate in a Bose gas could make it classical given the critical temperature $T_{c}$?

Comment: This could become a good question, but at the moment it's way too vague to attract decent answers. Please try to add more background to the question and explain what *specific* concept you do not understand.

Comment: I changed the question to make it more specific if you think it is still too vague help me formulate it better please!